# Installing python libs under Lubuntu 14.10 getting Errors

Tags: lubuntu, python, matplotlib

Hey there I need to install some python packages on my Laptop for work(university). The command they gave us is
`sudo apt-get install python3 python3-pip python3-pyqt4 python3-tk` and
`pip3 install --upgrade pyflakes pylint pygments pep8 numpy scipy matplotlib psutil sphinx rope-py3k`
but I have trouble installing scipy and matplotlib. I'm getting these errors:

```
Cleaning up...
Removing temporary dir /tmp/pip_build_chris...
Command /usr/bin/python3 -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip_build_chris/scipy/setup.py'  
exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" 
install --record /tmp/pip-te6a9qkh-record/install-record.txt 
--single-version-externally-managed --compile failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip_build_chris/scipy 
Exception information:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 122, in main status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 283, in run requirement_set.install(install_options,  
  global_options, root=options.root_path)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/req.py", line 1435, in install requirement.install(install_options, global_options, *args, 
 **kwargs)
 File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/req.py", line 706, in install cwd=self.source_dir, filter_stdout=self._filter_install,  
 show_stdout=False)
 File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/util.py", line 697, in call_subprocess% (command_desc, proc.returncode, cwd))
 pip.exceptions.InstallationError: Command /usr/bin/python3 -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip_build_chris
 /scipy /setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install 
 --record /tmp/pip-te6a9qkh-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile failed with error code 1 in 
 /tmp/pip_build_chris/scipy
```

And:

```
 Cleaning up...
 Removing temporary dir /tmp/pip_build_chris...
 Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip_build_chris/matplotlib
 Exception information:
 Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 122, in mainstatus = self.run(options, args)
 File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 278, in runrequirement_set.prepare_files(finder, 
 force_root_egg_info=self.bundle, bundle=self.bundle)
 File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/req.py", line 1229, in prepare_filesreq_to_install.run_egg_info()
 File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/req.py", line 325, in run_egg_infocommand_desc='python setup.py egg_info')
 File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/util.py", line 697, in call_subprocess% (command_desc, proc.returncode, cwd))
 pip.exceptions.InstallationError: Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip_build_chris 
 /matplotlib
```

Any chances I can get some help here?

Comment: Why not install them from the repositories as well?  `sudo apt-get install python3-scipy python3-matplotlib`     Same for the other libraries you install with pip.

Comment: Well I'm really new to Linux to I'm not sure what all of those commands really do in the end. I mean sudo apt-get install ... is pretty clear but pip3 for example. I guess it takes the python 3 packages only? Well  I will try to do it as you suggested maybe it works then :)

Comment: To follow up on Timo's answer: install them from the repo so that you have all the dependencies properly installed. Then install from a virtualenv so that you have the specific versions you want.

Comment: Could you eleborate on that or provide a link that explains the steps I should take for example for the virtualenv?